# Typescript interface allowing key of type, and string values

Tags: typescript

Is there a way in Typescript to use a known `type` as the key of an interface, dynamically?

For example, I have this `type`:

```
type properties = 'name' | 'age' | 'height';
```

and I want to allow an object that uses any/all of those "properties" as the key, and a string as the value:

`{name: 'abc', height: '2'}` or `{height: '2'}` allowed

I've done this with values, but not keys, so I'd want the opposite of this:

```
interface person {
  [key: string]: properties
}
```

Something like this:

```
interface person {
  [key: properties]: string
}
```

Comment: `type person = {
  [key in properties]?: string
}`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `type` for that:

```
type Properties = 'name' | 'age' | 'height';
type Person = {
    [key in Properties]: string
}

// This is allowed
const allowed: Person = {
    name: 'the-name',
    age: '21',
    height: '180',
}

// This has error
const errored: Person = {
    name: 'the-name',
    age: '21',
    height: '180',
    anotherKey: 'foo',
}
```

Comment: thanks! i added `?: string` to satisfy the optional cases.